Resuming from suspends disables laptop keyboard
How do you fix a non-responsive keyboard after reopening a closed the laptop lis?
I recently swapped out a broken keyboard on a Dell Precision 5520 running Ubuntu. At first boot, the new keyboard worked fine. However, I noticed that if I closed the laptop lid and reopen, the keyboard no longer works. Everything else is fine.
Plus, if I reboot, the keyboard works again, so I'm guessing it's some subtle software issue, although I'm not sure why it would start after replacing hardware with identical hardware. I rechecked my installation and all cables looked seated correctly and are undamaged.
If I activate suspend with:
systemctl suspend

resume and then check:
journalctl --system --boot=0 --priority=4

the only line that looks suspicious and related to the keyboard is:
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x411, Reinit

However, using some other guides, I noticed that the keyboard corresponds to /sys/class/input/input4 and after suspend, that file vanishes. Could these be related?
Since the keyboard works after reboot, even if there's a hardware fault, there's a state where it works, so is there any way to programmaticaly reset the device, to simulate it coming out of a reboot instead of suspend, to get it working again?
Other solutions I've tried, which had no effect:

I've tried forcing devices to be rescanned with:
sudo udevadm trigger --action=add

Rebinding the input subsystem with:
sudo modprobe -r usbhid
sudo modprobe usbhid
sudo modprobe -r hid_generic
sudo modprobe hid_generic


(Those fail because those modules are in-use.)

Restarting udev:
sudo systemctl restart systemd-udevd

Reloading the i8042 module:
sudo rmmod i8042
sudo modprobe i8042


(That fails because it says that module is built-in and can't be removed or reloaded.)

Offering a sacrifice of an unblemished calf. (This fixed it, but only for a couple minutes)

Is there anything else I haven't tried?

My laptop's keyboard is accessed via an internal USB interface. So my theory is that there's some issue with the new keyboard that causes it to not power back on after a suspend.
So I figured a potential solution would be to exempt USB from suspending.
To do that, I added:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"

to my sudo nano /etc/default/grub then ran sudo update-grub and rebooted, and sure enough, my keyboard now continues to work after suspend!
